# Invalid parameter config_hash: Attempting to install mysql (and Openstack) via Puppet

Tags: mysql, puppet, openstack

I've searched around for hints on how to solve this but I haven't been able to find anything concrete. I've seen [Puppet apache module causing 'Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter identifier'](https://serverfault.com/questions/448748/puppet-apache-module-causing-error-400-on-server-invalid-parameter-identifier) , but I'm using a fresh/single environment install and as a result don't believe I'm facing the same problem.

What I'm trying to accomplish:
I want to install Openstack via puppet using the provided modules on the Puppet Labs website. When I get to the stage where I'm installing mysql, I get an exciting error informing me that the module (openstack) is using an invalid parameter.

The error

> err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter config_hash at /etc/puppet/modules/openstack/manifests/db/mysql.pp:112 on node  controller.my.domain

Here is the corresponding bit of code.

```
# Install and configure MySQL Server
class { 'mysql::server':
config_hash => {
  'root_password' => $mysql_root_password,
  'bind_address'  => $mysql_bind_address,
  'ssl'           => $mysql_ssl,
  'ssl_ca'        => $mysql_ca,
  'ssl_cert'      => $mysql_cert,
  'ssl_key'       => $mysql_key,
},
enabled     => $enabled,
} <- Line 112
```

Now the MySQL password and bind address have been specified, but not the ssl parameters which I honestly don't think should affect what I'm doing. I've commented them out just to see what would happen and I still get the same error. I'm pretty sure the code itself is fine but I'm just missing a library or something along those lines, but my searching hasn't turned up anything useful.

Google did come up with a few suggestions but I don't think they apply, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/CC83xP0AGEg . In this case the code I'm using appears to be properly formed. I was also reading that "config_hash parameter collapsed for the postgresql::server class", but I'm not using postgresql (https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/postgresql - scroll down).

I'm using the puppetlabs openstack module and its dependencies including the stdlib, apache, mysql, contact, and puppetdb. It's very possible I haven't configured one of these properly.  Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of the `mysql` module do you have installed?  (check its Modulefile)

Looks like the `openstack` modules depend on behavior of older versions of the `mysql` module, and declare that correctly in their dependencies - they seem to be happy only with 0.9.0.

Assuming you're not using the mysql module elsewhere, try downgrading to that version.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm using the latest mysql module 2.2.3, I was thinking of getting an earlier version but the "build failing" image tags scared me away, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Phil One way to make sure you've got the right dependencies is to use the `puppet module install` command line tool - it will install the versions of dependencies that the module requires.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, will definitely keep that in mind after today's experience. I thought I was okay with dependencies since the module homepage left it out ( https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/openstack ). Lesson learned. By the way, what you suggested worked first try, thank you again!